# How to Customise the Alert OK / Cancel buttons using this aritchie/userdialogs in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Hi I am new to Xamarin Forms and am from native iOS development.

For showing alerts / action sheets I am using this https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs.

For implementing this I followed this [How to use Acr.UserDialogs](https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-use-acr-userdialogs/).

I am getting alert successfully by following this, but now **I need to customise the OK / Cancel Button's background color, alignment, frame values, hide and show the buttons.**.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it's being set based on the platform defaults colors and arrangement. Some of those things I don't recommend you to change, btw.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to customise the OK / Cancel Button's background color, alignment, frame values, hide and show the buttons.

As the author [said](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/504), you could do this by creating a style and apply it in AlertConfig.
For example:
In the style.xml:

```
 <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#AAAAAA</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">#DDDDDD</item>
   <!-- Used for the Alignment -->
   <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

And you could find this style Id in the `Resource.Designer.cs`.

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7f0b0189
public const int AlertDialogCustom = 2131427721;
```

Then in the code create a AlertConfig to config the alertdialog:

```
AlertConfig alertConfig = new AlertConfig();
alertConfig.OkText = "OKOK";
alertConfig.Message = "Message";
alertConfig.Title = "Title";
alertConfig.AndroidStyleId=2131427721;            
UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(alertConfig);
```

Comment: You should NEVER hard code aapt resource values, as they might change as you add new resources or when the version changes. Reference the values from the R class.

Answer (score 1):

With [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) Nuget you can customize the popup.

Comment: Thank you, now I will try this.

Comment: Give me feedback, please.

Comment: Hi Miguel Angel, Finally I am not using this and any other nuggets also.
I created my own custom alert, and paced it in custom controls folder and then I used when ever I required in other classes.
Thank you for support and sorry for lately reply.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am not using any nugget packages. Now I created my own CustomAlert class. I hope it will helpful for any one.

@Miguel Angel please look at below code

In my CustomAlert.xaml  file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="wwww/2009/xaml" x:Class="MY.UserControls.CustomAlert">

<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0"> 

      <Grid BackgroundColor="#656565" Opacity="0.5">
       </Grid>

      <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WhiteColor}"                     VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10" Padding="10" >

<Label  Text="Title" FontSize="18" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextColor="Black"></Label>

<Label  Text="Descrption." FontSize="14" 
HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
Margin="10,10,5,5" 
VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Gray"></Label>

<Button Text="OK" TextColor="{StaticResource WhiteColor}"
Command="{Binding DismissCustomAlertCommand}" 
HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" 
BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="30,0,30,0" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="40"></Button>

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
 </ContentView>
```

Thank you